# How to prevent exception catching when we need to throw custom exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

```
  void connectOverNetwork() throws Exception {
    try {
      final JSONObject response = make network call;

      if (!response.getBoolean(SUCCESS)) {
        LOG.error("--- foo message ---");
        throw new Exception("message replied with error");
      }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      LOG.error("---- bar message ---");
      throw new SvcException("failed to connect over network");
    }
  }
```

In the code above, I am throwing an exception with a failure message. 
At the same time, I am also throwing an error on failure to connect over the network.

But, if I throw an exception for `!success` it gets caught again, causing duplicate logging. I do not want to print `bar message`, if I only want to log `foo message`.

How to prevent it from happening?

Comment: Why can't you remove it from there?

Comment: what API do you use for making network calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validate the `response` after the `try-catch` statement.

```
JSONObject response = null;
try {
    response = /* make network call */;
} catch (final Exception e) {
    LOG.error("---- bar message ---");
    throw new SvcException("failed to connect over network");
}

if (!response.getBoolean(SUCCESS)) {
    LOG.error("--- foo message ---");
    throw new Exception("message replied with error");
}
```

I don't recommend catching `Exception` - it's too general, I suggest you narrow it down to a more specific exception type.

Comment: You should wrap the caught exception inside the SvcException. You should also throw SvcException instead of Exception on the last line.

Comment: @MiguelMunoz, I didn't get it. Could you clarify it a bit?

Comment: Whenever you catch one exception and throw another, you should always wrap the first exception inside the second. You can usually pass it in to the constructor. If not, you can set it using Throwable's initCause() method. See my answer below.

Comment: @MiguelMunoz, I may or may not wrap the cause up with a new exception (I could extract needed information and forget about it, I could be just not interested in the cause)

Comment: @MiguelMunoz it is surely a good practice, but it's rather voluntary, not mandatory

Comment: I would call it "advisable." And I would leave it up to the user to decide if they're interested in the cause. The inner exception that you're concealing may well be a new bug that creeps into the code in the future. The extra information provided by the wrapped exception does no harm, and may one day surprise you when you actually need it. So I see no advantage to leaving it out, especially since it costs me nothing to include it. In my debugging experience, I have often needed to first rewrite someone's code to expose the original exception. Wrapping exceptions is a professional courtesy.

Answer (score 1):

What if you move it outside the `try` block.. Anyway, the reason for the first `try..catch` is to catch any Exception from the network call.

```
JSONObject response = null;
try {
    response = make network call;
} catch (final Exception e) {
    LOG.error("---- bar message ---");
    throw new SvcException("failed to connect over network");
}
if (!response.getBoolean(SUCCESS)) {
    LOG.error("--- foo message ---");
    throw new Exception("message replied with error");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let me point out a mistake in your code. Your method declares that it throws Exception, but it doesn't. It throws SvcException. So that's what the "throws" clause should say. (You should never say "throws Exception" anyway. You should state explicitly what kind of exception it throws.) The rest of the answer depends on whether or not your vague description "make network call" throws an exception or not.

If it doesn't, your method should look like this:

```
void connectOverNetwork() throws SvcException {
  final JSONObject response = makeNetworkCall();

  if (!response.getBoolean(SUCCESS)) {
    LOG.error("--- foo message ---");
    throw new SvcException("message replied with error");
  }
}
```

But that's unrealistic. Chances are, your "make network call" code throws something like IOException. In this case your code should look like this:

```
void connectOverNetwork() throws SvcException {
  try {
    final JSONObject response = makeNetworkCall(); // throws IOException

    if (!response.getBoolean(SUCCESS)) {
      LOG.error("--- foo message ---");
      throw new SvcException("message replied with error");
    }
  } catch (final IOException e) {
    LOG.error("--- foo message ---");
    throw new SvcException("failed to connect", e); // wrap e inside SvcException
  }
}
```

Notice that I wrap the caught IOException inside the SvcException. If your SvcException doesn't do that, either rewrite it so that it can, or call its `initCause()` method before throwing it. You should always include the original exception when reThrowing a different exception.

Also notice that I don't bother throwing, then catching and rethrowing an IOException. When I detect failure. I just throw the exception that I need to throw. This means I need to log the foo message in two separate places. For most things, repeating a line of code should be avoided, but for logging, this is fine.

But this code is a bit messy. I would clean it up by separating the test for success from the possible IOException. So I would write it like this:

```
void connectOverNetwork() throws SvcException {
  JSONObject response; // no need to initialize this.
  try {
    response = makeNetworkCall(); // throws IOException
  } catch (final IOException e) {
    LOG.error("--- foo message ---");
    throw new SvcException("failed to connect", e); // wrap e inside SvcException
  }

  if (!response.getBoolean(SUCCESS)) {
    LOG.error("--- foo message ---");
    throw new SvcException("message replied with error");
  }
}
```

Notice here that response is declared before the try loop. It's not initialized because there's no way it will reach the `!response.getBoolean(SUCCESS)` test without a value. If makeNetworkCall() throws an exception, it won't even reach that line.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own exception type and don't catch it.

```
try {
    do stuff
    if (condition) 
        throw new MyCustomException("error")
} catch (IOException e) {
    log and rethrow
}
```